# 'X is not a template' error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I'm having trouble declaring a template class. I've tried an number of ill-readable and non-sensical combinations.

```
template <class C, class M >
class BlockCipherGenerator : public KeyGenerator
{
  ...
  private:
      M < C > m_cipher;
};
```

And

```
template <class C, class M >
class BlockCipherGenerator : public KeyGenerator
{
  typedef typename C::value_type CIPHER;
  typedef typename M::value_type MODE;
  private:
      MODE < CIPHER > m_cipher;
};
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's what it says.

Your template parameter list says that [`M` is a `class`, not a `template`](http://codepad.org/m7CYnTo6).

If you say that it's a class *template*, [then everything's fine](http://codepad.org/2QbAU7bI):

```
template <class C, template <class C> class M>
class BlockCipherGenerator : public KeyGenerator
{
      M<C> m_cipher;
};
```

---

Remember, something like `std::vector` is *not* a class, but a class template. Something like `std::vector<int>` is a class (type).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I actually had it, but I let errors in the CPP file distract me.

Comment: @noloader: No problem at all. :)