# How to code a union using a struct as template, while having that union as an element

Tags: c++, struct, binary-tree, unions, crtp

1. I am trying to construct a union that will replace the pair of pointers (left & right)
   by a union which is accessible as an array.
   Originally this is working code for a Binary Search Tree (BST)

I want to be able to do this:

```
p = p->pLR.array[value>insertValue];
```

in addition to the old branched

```
if(value>insertValue) p = p->right;
else  p = p->left;
```

1b. This is not exactly to avoid costly branching misprediction,
but simply to be able to *learn* to implement [something] like this.

2. Mostly the problem that BinaryNode is templated in the union, and the union is an element of the BinaryNode!

Here is my non-compiling code-in-progress:

```
template    <class dataType, class BinaryNode<dataType> >
union BinaryNodePointerPair {
struct {
        BinaryNode<dataType> *left;
        BinaryNode<dataType> *right;
    };
    BinaryNode<dataType> *array[2]; 
};  
template    <class dataType>
struct BinaryNode {
    dataType    value;
    BinaryNodePointerPair<dataType,BinaryNode<dataType> > pLR;
};
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template
```

refactored from:

```
template    <class dataType>
struct BinaryNode {
    dataType    value;
    BinaryNode  *left;
    BinaryNode  *right;
};
```

3. What I have tried so far:

3a. According to   ['X is not a template' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970219/x-is-not-a-template-error)
the template should be

```
template    <class dataType, class <dataType>BinaryNode >
[Error] expected identifier before '<' token
[Error] expected '>' before '<' token
[Error] type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class dataType, int <anonymous> > union BinaryNodePointerPair'
```

3b. So i change it to

```
template    <class dataType, class BinaryNode<dataType> >
```

But this gives the errors, plus the original.

```
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a class template
[Error] 'class BinaryNode' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template
```

3c. So i again change it to

```
template    <class dataType, class BinaryNode<dataType> >
```

but this gives even more errors

```
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a class template
[Error] 'class BinaryNode' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template type
```

3d. Now, this is eerily close to CRTP
(no need to tell me this isnt real CRTP, but it is curiously)

```
template    <class dataType>
union BinaryNodePointerPair {
struct {
    BinaryNode<dataType> *left;
    BinaryNode<dataType> *right;
};
BinaryNode<dataType> *array[2]; 
};  
template    <class dataType, BinaryNodePointerPair<dataType> >
struct BinaryNode {
    dataType    value;
    BinaryNodePointerPair<dataType> pLR;
};
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template
```

Only 1 error! WOW! This has got to be a winner!

3e. Now I really really force-pattern it into CRTP... it's even worse.

```
template    <class dataType, class BinaryNode<dataType> >
union BinaryNodePointerPair {
    struct {
        BinaryNode<dataType> *left;
        BinaryNode<dataType> *right;
    };
    BinaryNode<dataType> *array[2]; 
};  
template    <class dataType>
struct BinaryNode {
    dataType    value;
    BinaryNodePointerPair<dataType, BinaryNode<dataType>> pLR;
};
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a class template
[Error] 'class BinaryNode' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
[Error] 'BinaryNode' is not a template
```

It doesn't have to be CRTP. 
Is there a way to do it?

How do I write a union w/ pointers to a struct having an element of that union?

Comment: to the rush downvoter: might I know what is wrong with the question?
Which principle of "how to ask a good question" did I violate?

How should I modify the question to make it better?

Comment: I downvoted, since I made some edits that are considered good here (reducing chat and meta commentary) and you overwrote them in a subsequent edit. (In general I do not recommend asking why people downvoted, since you will rarely get an answer - most people will vote and move on).

Comment: Have you actually observed a performance problem with just the struct? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75390/why-should-i-care-about-micro-performance-and-efficency

Comment: Good point with the premature optimization.
The presumed performance issue is with the constant branching, not the struct.
My goal is to create an alternative and then compare.
But yes, I've not yet observed any real issues or bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get the question, but did you perhaps forget the forward declaration of `BinaryNode`?

```
template <class dataType>
struct BinaryNode;

template <class dataType>
union BinaryNodePointerPair
{
  struct
  {
    BinaryNode<dataType> *left;
    BinaryNode<dataType> *right;
  };
  BinaryNode<dataType> *array[2]; 
};

template <class dataType>
struct BinaryNode
{
  dataType value;
  BinaryNodePointerPair<dataType> pLR;
};
```

Comment: This actually works!
I'd be pretty much ashamed of myself if I was not so ecstatic!

How do I mark this as the answer?